# Identify similar sub-images with in a frame

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on a project which involves counting of similar objects stacked up. Identifying similar sub-images for counting would be a better way or is there any better way?
 [Click here for a sample frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cBkL.png)

Comment: any better way than what? please read [ask].

Comment: "Identifying similar sub-images for counting" is the problem at hand. By stating that, you didn't move forward by an inch.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are nicely stacked and well-contrasted as on the picture, you can find the outline and estimate the outer dimensions.

Then by overlaying a regular grid that fits the outer edges, you can delimit smaller windows that single out the objects. Then verify the hypothesis by direct comparison of the subimages.

In the given picture, there is a single box at the top, and this gives enough clue to estimate the size of the individual boxes. But if the boxes are arranged to fill a rectangle, this is no more possible. Then you should try and compare different hypothesis.

Another way to estimate the box size is by means of autocorrelation: you can pick a subwindow in the middle of the image and correlate it to the rest of the image, using a 2D FFT. The correlation peaks will tell you the size.